# Online state change

Tags: bash, python, ping

Are there ready script in bash or python which pings target and reports only online state change? Also would nice to have average time between failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ping_online_offline()
    {
            SECONDS=0
            avg=-1
            ping_log $1
            while true; do
                    while fping -r1 -q $1; do sleep 1; done
                    test $avg -eq -1 && avg=$SECONDS
                            # Cumulative moving average for 5
                            let avg+=(SECONDS-avg)/5
                    echo "$SECONDS seconds till $(date +%T), offline moving MTBF = $((avg/60)) min $((avg%60)) sec"
                    SECONDS=0
                    while ! fping -r1 -q $1; do sleep 1; done
                    echo -en " $SECONDS seconds, till $(date +%T) \tonline "
                    SECONDS=0
            done
    }
```